# Leetcode - product of array except self

Tags: java, array, interview-questions

> Given an array nums of n integers where n > 1,  return an array output
>   such that output[i] is equal to the product of all the elements of
>   nums except nums[i].

**Example:**

```
Input:  [1,2,3,4]
Output: [24,12,8,6]
Note: Please solve it without division and in O(n).
```

> Follow up: Could you solve it with constant space complexity? (The
>   output array does not count as extra space for the purpose of space
>   complexity analysis.)

My solution

```
public class ProductExceptSelf {
    /**
     * Approach 1:- Find the left[i] at i containing all the left multiplication. Do same with right[i]
     */
    public int[] productExceptSelf(int[] nums) {

        int size = nums.length;

        int[] output = new int[size];
        int[] left = new int[size];
        int[] right = new int[size];

        int temp = 1;
        // Start filling up left array
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            left[i] = temp;
            temp = temp * nums[i];
        }

        // Again set the temp to 1
        temp = 1;

        // Start filling up right array
        for (int i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            right[i] = temp;
            temp = temp * nums[i];
        }

        // Final traversal and return sum array.
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            output[i] = left[i] * right[i];
        }

        return output;
    }
}
```

Please help me to improve Auxilary space, code readibility and any best practice if I am missing.

Answer (score 2):

Every time you feel obliged to put a comment like

```
    // Start filling up left array
```

you really deal with a potentially important algorithm, which deserves a name, and a method of its own. In this case the algorithm is known as *partial product*. Consider factoring it out, and see the comments disappear.

Ditto for the second loop.

Regarding space complexity,

- You don't need `left`: accumulate the partial products directly into `output`.
- You don't need `right` as well: instead of accumulating the partial products, use it immediately:

  ```
      temp = 1;

      for (int i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
          output[i] *= temp;
          temp = temp * nums[i];
      }
  ```